# Casting struct* to void*

Tags: c, casting, sonarqube, void

I have a following function in C:

```
Bool message(void* msg, unsigned timeout);
```

and a structure that I want to pass to that function:

```
msgSPI_t msgSPI; //msgSPI_t is of struct type
```

like so:

```
message(&msgSPI, (unsigned)0)
```

Now, this works as intended, but since I am using SonarQube for code quality inspection, I get a bug for passing `&msgSPI`:

> "Remove this hazardous cast." (according to MISRA C:2004, 11.2 and 11.3).

Since function `message` is a 3rd party code, I can't (or shouldn't) change it. What would be a good solution here, that would satisfy Sonar complaints? (adding `(void*)` in front of `&msgSPI` clears the bug, but I am not sure if that's the correct way to do this.)

Comment: This cast is perfectly valid.. it is *not* a bug. The MISRA is known for producing overzealous warning for many safe constructs just because once upon the time some engineer has shot their (or someone's) foot by using a given construct incorrectly.

Comment: my 2 cents, casting to `void*` works for me, altho I'm surprised SonarQube is complaining about that (I know very little about it). It's perfectly valid to cast a pointer type to `void*` (see `memcpy` for instance). I've come to learn that a big enough code base is littered with exceptions for the code analyzers. They're not perfect, just supposed to draw your attention to something that may be a problem. Cast to `void*` or add a comment exception.

Comment: ignore MISRA; it makes code much more insecure because it requires unsafe casts everywhere.

Comment: Tip: I'd use `0U` over `(unsigned)0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume this is a length-prefixed block. In a language with inheritance, you'd use something like this:

```c
class BaseMessage {
   uint32_t size;
};

class MyMessage extends BaseMessage {
   // ...
};

bool message( BaseMessage *msg, unsigned timeout );

MyMessage my_message;
my_message.size = sizeof( MyMessage );
...

message( &my_message, timeout );
```

C doesn't have inheritance. Instead, you tend to see

```c
bool message( void *msg_body, size_t msg_body_size, unsigned timeout );
```

But that would require `message` to build the message, possibly involving a memory allocation. This pattern might be wasteful. And it still uses `void *`.

Trying to implement inheritance using unions or whatnot would be messy, and they wouldn't really add any value. You'd just add code and thus complexity to end up with what is effectively just a cast.

So this is a false positive. These are to be expected from linters, so you should have a process in place to handle these.

I would prefer a process that flags certain warnings expected, but it could maybe be silenced using the following:

```c
// Silence SonarQube false positive.
#define message( msg, timeout ) message( (void*)(msg), (timeout) )

message( &msgSPI, 0U )
```

I would strongly recommend against using a cast at the call site of each use of `message`. Pointer casts are dangerous as the defy the type system. The above does have a cast, which is why it's not my preferred approach. But it's only one location, so it's more easily managed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for an extensive answer / explanation. I was also confused by this bug from SonarQube, and it seems I am not lonely in thinking that it might be a false positive.